# Is there a way to do var args for a structure implementation in rust without macros?

Tags: rust

I've seen this style of var args in the past:

```
#![feature(macro_rules)]

struct Foo;

impl Foo {
  fn add2(&self, a:int, b:int) -> int {
    return a + b;
  }
  fn add3(&self, a:int, b:int, c:int) -> int {
    return a + b + c;
  }
  fn add4(&self, a:int, b:int, c:int, d:int) -> int {
    return a + b + c + d;
  }
}

macro_rules! add(
  ($foo:ident, $a:expr, $b:expr) => (
    $foo.add2($a, $b);
  );
  ($foo:ident, $a:expr, $b:expr, $c:expr) => (
    $foo.add3($a, $b, $c);
  );
  ($foo:ident, $a:expr, $b:expr, $c:expr, $d:expr) => (
    $foo.add4($a, $b, $c, $d);
  );
)

fn main() {
  let foo = Foo;
  println!("Add:{}", add!(foo, 1, 2));
  println!("Add:{}", add!(foo, 1, 2, 3));
  println!("Add:{}", add!(foo, 1, 2, 3, 4));
}
```

(and yes, that's right, I use explicit returns, because the ; / no ; semantics terrible imo)

Anyway, Is there a way to do a similar thing without having to use the awkward call!(obj, ...) syntax, and use the more natural obj.call(...) syntax you'd normally use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust does not at present have support for variadic functions.<sup>†</sup>

An alternative, more idiomatic design is using arrays and iterating:

```rust
fn add(&self, numbers: &[int]) -> int {
    numbers.iter().sum() // … or whatever iteration stuff you want
}
```

When making optimised builds with method inlining (you can put `#[inline]` on the method and then it will work cross-crate also), this will be just as efficient as a arbitrary functions with many arguments, if LLVM optimiser believes that will be cheaper.

---

<sup>†</sup> Actually it does, but only for extern functions of the C ABI. Not for Rust functions.